# unable to load asset until perform hot loading in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When i uploaded the file from the file picker the data should insert directly into the cloud firestore collection , but i cannot upload until i perform a hot loading in flutter (ctrl + s) then the record can  uploaded into the firebase collection successfully. How can i upload the data directly to the firebase without reload again by clicking control-save to perform hot loading ?

The error i got in the console :
E/flutter (10276): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: /data/user/0/com.example.simple_flutter_database/cache/file_picker/sampleData-Copy.xlsx

```
  final databaseReference = Firestore.instance;
  // This function is triggered when the floating button is pressed
  Future _loadCSV() async {
    String filePath = await FilePicker.getFilePath();
    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(filePath);
    var bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
    var excel = Excel.decodeBytes(bytes);
    for (var table in excel.tables.keys) {
      for (var row in excel.tables[table].rows) {
        await databaseReference.collection("vehicles").add({
          'Car_Make': row[3],
          'Company': row[4],
          'Holder_Type': row[2],
          'Holder_Name': row[1],
          'Vehicle_No': row[0],
        });
      }
      return Row();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You loading a file, not an asset. Files from a device's filesystem loading with `File` class.

```dart
final file = File(filePath);
final content = file.readAsStringSync();
```

Comment: how can i load and read the file ? is there any method except this rootBundle.root ? because when i control-save it works .

Comment: E/flutter (14458): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.
E/flutter (14458): Receiver: null
E/flutter (14458): Tried calling: length

Comment: What operation on file do you do?

Comment: Upload csv file into firebase cloud firestore collection

Comment: Where you getting an error? Line in code.